# How to Auto-layout and deploy app to app store

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, app-store

I am new in IOS Development.I am learning auto layout for all device in portrait and landscape.

When I apply constraint to view or any controls it gives me warning for Ambiguous Layouts or any other warnings but in run time it looks perfect.
Please give me links to study and refer for autolayout.

**So, I want to know that:-**

**1) I have multi storyboard for each device screensize in my app storyboard will load as per screensize of device [Load storyboard depending on screensize](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-load-a-different-storyboard-depending-on-screen-size-in-ios/) (Is this legal if I deploy app to app store ?)**

**2) if I have any coding warning or layout warning will apple accept it to deploy in app store ? And what are the rules to deploy an app to app store.**

Please forgive me if I have put wrong question.

Thank you...

Comment: yes , you can deploy it. Apple will not reject your app untill you will break rules. warning is not an issue]

Comment: is multi storyboard idea is good for apple?

Comment: yes, it does not matter what you use. we can use multiple storyboard as per our requirement.

Comment: but i suggest you that use one storyboard and using AutoLayout you can manage all this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It's no problem for Apple that you have multiple Storyboards and they'll not reject your app because of it.

2) Apple will not reject your app based on compiler/code or layout warnings. It's always a good practice to get rid of the warnings though as they are there for a reason. The rules and guidelines to follow are listed in the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

When I learned to develop for iOS the tutorials from [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/) helped me a lot. For example [this Auto Layout Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) will probably help you get started.